# How to authenticate a user against AD in Java

Tags: java, authentication, ldap, jndi

I'm using JNDI library to access to an AD from Java Webapp. I authenticate agaisnt the AD via LDAP using a technical user as follows:

```
    Hashtable<String, String> ldapEnv = new Hashtable<String, String>(11);
    ldapEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITIAL_CONTEXT);
    ldapEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, providerUrl);
    ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,
            SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION_SIMPLE);
    ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, principal);
    ldapEnv.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, credentials);
    return new InitialDirContext(ldapEnv);
```

I use this user to read and write from/to AD.

But after that, I don't know how to authenticate the final user who is really accessing to my webapp with his user and a password.

I read about using find method from Context class but I'm not sure how to do or how to build the the search filter. For example

```
(&(cn= ....
```

I don't know either how to find for all users in the AD. I would like to show in my webapp a list of all available users in AD

Comment: Which Application/Web server are you using? Glassfish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

-To Authenticate a user

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "LDAP://url/");

env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "domain\\user_name");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password");

InitialLdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env,null);
boolean authenticated = (ctx != null) ? true : false;
```

-To Get all users' names

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllUsers(LdapContext ctx) {
    ArrayList<String> users = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();
        constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

        String[] attrIDs = {"cn"};
        constraints.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);

        NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search("dc=example,dc=com", "(&(cn=*))", constraints);

        while (answer.hasMore()) {
            Attributes attrs = ((SearchResult) answer.next()).getAttributes();
            users.add(attrs.get("cn").toString().replace("cn:", ""));
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    return users;
}
```

-To Search a particular use

```
public String getUserName(String username, LdapContext ctx) {
    try {
        SearchControls constraints = new SearchControls();
        constraints.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

        String[] attrIDs = {"cn"};
        constraints.setReturningAttributes(attrIDs);

        NamingEnumeration answer = ctx.search("OU=Employees,OU=Users,DC=sub_domain,DC=domain,DC=com", "uid=" + username, constraints);

        if (answer.hasMore()) {
            Attributes attrs = ((SearchResult) answer.next()).getAttributes();
            return attrs.get("cn").toString().replace("cn:", "");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

You can get more details about search query from
 [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18756688/what-are-cn-ou-dc-in-an-ldap-search)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the same for each user to authenticate.

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/ldap.html

If you get the context for that user, that means username & password is correct. If not, not you get the exception & send it o user login screen etc.

Don't forget to close the Context in finally block if authenticated.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this link will save your day:
http://www.javaxt.com/Tutorials/Windows/How_to_Authenticate_Users_with_Active_Directory
You can authenticate a user and list users of a domain.

Answer (score 2):

-To authenticate you need to create dir context , just like you mentioned in you question, for each user trying to to login.

--Or if you have Weblogic as your Appserver , you can make use of WL container authentication to handle user login by configuring AD as an authenticatoe in WL and protecting your login URL. : Read more  [Configuring container-managed security in Weblogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931119/configuring-container-managed-security-in-weblogic)

-To list all users under a Root DSE or a certain Base DN

1. Create a Dir Context to pointing to the Root DSE or a DN under it

   DirContext ctx = InitialDirContext(ldapEnv);
2. Do context.search() passing returning attributes, search controls and the search filter matching user object classes and login attribute

   SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
   controls.setReturningAttributes(new String[]{"cn" ,"objectGUID"});
   controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
   String filter = "(&(cn=*)(|(objectclass=person)    (objectclass=organizationalPerson)))";

   NamingEnumeration searchResult = ctx.search("", filter, controls);

-To search a particular user , modify the filter to match the user cn or any other attribute

```
String filter = "(&(cn=Rafa Romero)(|(objectclass=person)(objectclass=organizationalPerson)))";
```

Answer (score 2):

Most servlet containers can be configured to authenticate via LDAP, that would be significantly more secure and reliable than rolling your own authentication code.

[For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10192981/how-do-i-set-up-tomcat-with-authentication-in-ldap)